# xml парсинг на delphi

Tags: delphi, xml

Есть xml документ:

```
<trackers type="array">
<tracker>
<id>3</id>
<name>issues</name>
<default_status id="1" name="new"/>
</tracker>
<tracker>
<id>1</id>
<name>errors</name>
<default_status id="1" name="new"/>
</tracker>
<tracker>
<id>2</id>
<name>utest</name>
<default_status id="1" name="new"/>
</tracker>
</trackers>
```

Как правильно на delphi его разобрать, чтобы получить все id и name из секции tracker? Желательно с помощью стандартных компонентов, TXMLDocument etc.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть как минимум 2 способа получить из xml только нужные параметры: задействовать [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) или "пробежаться" самому по элементам.

```pascal
uses
  Xml.XMLIntf,
  Xml.Xmldom,
  Xml.XMLDoc;

procedure TForm6.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XML: IXMLDocument;
  Nodes: IXMLNodeList;
  TrackerNode: IXMLNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // загружаем XML из вопроса.
  XML:=LoadXMLData(
  '<trackers type="array"><tracker><id>3</id><name>issues</name><default_status id="1" name="new"/>' +
'</tracker><tracker><id>1</id><name>errors</name><default_status id="1" name="new"/></tracker><tracker>' +
'<id>2</id><name>utest</name><default_status id="1" name="new"/></tracker></trackers>');
  // ====================================
  // способ 1, используем XPath
  Nodes:=SelectNodesX(XML.DocumentElement, '//trackers/tracker/id|//trackers/tracker/name');

  for i := 0 to Nodes.Count-1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Nodes[i].NodeName + ' = ' + Nodes[i].Text);

  Memo1.Lines.Add('==============');

  // ====================================
  // способ 2, выводим сами
  for i := 0 to XML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
    begin
      TrackerNode:=XML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i];
      // задействовать ChildValues лучше, если вы 100% уверены, что нод существует
      // в любом случае лучше подобное обрамлять проверками типа
      // if Assigned(TrackerNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('id')) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TrackerNode.ChildValues['id']);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TrackerNode.ChildValues['name']);
    end;
end;
```

Функция, используемая в первом способе для получения результата работы XPath-выражения выглядит так:

```pascal
function SelectNodesX(xnRoot: IXMLNode; const nodePath: string): IXMLNodeList;
var
  intfSelect: IDomNodeSelect;
  intfAccess: IXmlNodeAccess;
  dnlResult: IDomNodeList;
  intfDocAccess: IXmlDocumentAccess;
  doc: TXmlDocument;
  i: integer;
  dn: IDomNode;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(xnRoot) or not Supports(xnRoot, IXmlNodeAccess, intfAccess) or not Supports(xnRoot.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;

  dnlResult := intfSelect.SelectNodes(nodePath);
  if Assigned(dnlResult) then
    begin
      Result := TXmlNodeList.Create(intfAccess.GetNodeObject, '', nil);
      if Supports(xnRoot.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
        doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
      else
        doc := nil;

      for i := 0 to dnlResult.length - 1 do
        begin
          dn := dnlResult.item[i];
          Result.Add(TXmlNode.Create(dn, nil, doc));
        end;
    end;
end;
```

**Примечание** если предполагается работа кода на разных платформах (Win, iOS, Android) лучше пользоваться вторым способом, поскольку кросс-платформенные парсеры пока не в полном объеме реализуют синтаксис XPath.

Comment: спасибо! сейчас буду пробовать!